# Would it be correct English to omit the "t" when pronouncing words that end with "cts" like "acts of parliament"?

Tags: pronunciation

Some native speakers seem to omit the "t" in words that end with "cts" and others don't. Is one way more correct than the other or is there any connotation to be observed? I can see no way to look this up in a dictionary. 
To my mind other existing threads don't cover this question completely.

Comment: Could you describe how some of these words are pronounced without the "i" ?  .

Comment: It's not only correct English, it's the norm. _Facts_ is pronounced /fæks/ by native speakers unless they are hyperventilating or performing auditorily. And you can't look it up in a dictionary, because those list only official pronunciations, not the whole range of what people actually say.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you very much for your explanation!